# Jquery: Select the element that called the function

Tags: jquery

I'm calling a function in the element itself via an `onclick` attribute because I need php to dynamically give a value in one of the function's parameters. When I try to reference the calling element in the function via `$(this)`, it ends up referencing the entire window and not the element. How do I fix this?

Comment: This is a good question, and while the supplied answers suggest some workarounds, none of them address the original question. I'd like to know the answer as well. Why does he get the window for $(this), instead of the clicked element?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I doubt you genuinely do need to use an inline `onclick` attribute.  You can store data in an element in a variety of different ways.  It's hard to say exactly how you would do it without knowing what the parameter you need to pass is, but I'll give some examples.

The most flexible would probably be in a `data-` attribute:

```
<a href="#" id="subject" data-type="fiction">Text</a>
```

You could then access the information in the following way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#subject').click(function(){
        $type = $(this).data('type'); // this works as of jQuery 1.4.3, otherwise $(this).attr('data-type');

        // do your handling here, using $type
    });
});
```

You could also do this using classes, script tags that create global variables, all kinds of methods.  These will almost certainly be better than putting jQuery handlers in `onclick` attributes.

Answer (score 29):

Try to send your element as a parameter to your function like that :

```
<input type="text" onclick="myfunction(this);"></input>
```

your function should be :

```
<script>
  function myfunction(currentElement){
    // ...
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to store the dynamic value in a custom attribute, not an onclick handler. The HTML spec defines any attribute starting with "data-" as custom data used exactly for things like this, and it's in the spec so it will validate. So you can do something like this (using PHP for the example, adjust accordingly):

```
<input type="text" id="some-input" data-some-dynamic="<?php echo $something; ?>">
```

Then retrieve in the javascript like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#some-input').click(function() {
    // $(this) -- is the input element
    // $(this).attr('some-dynamic-attribute') -- contains the dynamic data you need
  });
});
```

I think this method is superior to using attribute handlers like onclick="", simple because it is more solid from a design perspective; separation of concerns and all that.

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out answer. Although not necessarily what I needed, a very interesting method.

Comment: Allen -- this answer is the same as the one lonesomeday gave you along with an alternative.

Comment: This answer originally had two alternatives, but since HTML5 is now supported among all modern browsers, I've updated the answer to only include the "data-X" solution.