# Get the DOM element that calls Javascript without an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've looked at these answers but they all talk about (click) events:
[Jquery: Select the element that called the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057702/jquery-select-the-element-that-called-the-function)
[Getting the ID of the element that fired an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event-using-jquery)
[Get information of element that called function with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555421/get-information-of-element-that-called-function-with-jquery)

But what if there is no event that triggers the code? What if the script is already sitting inside the DOM element on page load like this:

```
<div>
  <script>drawChip()</script>
</div>
```

How would I get a reference to the `div` element that calls this script using jQuery or Javascript?  I've tried `this` but that didn't work.

Comment: you could give the div an id

Comment: @MarcB no it wouldn't.

Comment: @pointy: yeah. fingers running ahead of brain. realized it wasn't an onclick handler.

Comment: The quick and easy answer:  Don't put your script there!  There's no good reason to.  Put all your scripts just inside the closing body tag. Place the method within a DOM-ready wrapper and target the div with the appropriate selectors.

Comment: There is no convenient way to get it automatically like event.target.id. You can pass the element id as parameter to the drawChip function.\

Comment: @DerekHenderson Thanks, your comment made me realize I need to change the way I'm implementing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really accurate to say that the `<div>` "calls" the script. The script is just sitting there and happens to be inside the `<div>` element, but that fact is uninteresting to the JavaScript runtime.

What you can do is something like this:

```
<div>
  <script id='script1234'>
    var parentElement = document.getElementById('script1234').parentNode;
    drawChip(parentElement);
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead::

```
var scriptDIVs = $("div").has("script")
```

Hope this will help !!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <script>drawChip(document.getElementById("myDiv") );</script>
</div>
```